# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments

Tags: php, function, php-7.3

How can I fix this problem?
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_config(), 1 passed in
my code is :

```
$site_name = get_config('site_name');
// Get site configuration

function get_config($conn, $setting_name) {

$setting_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT value FROM settings WHERE setting = '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "$setting_name"). "'");

return mysqli_result($setting_query, 0);

}
```

Comment: You're missing the `$conn` argument to the function, it needs to be your database connection object.

Answer (score -1):

The function takes 2 arguments: `$conn` and `$setting_name`. You're only passing 1, that I assume is `$setting_name`, it's missing `$conn` argument.